# Recursividade em Java

Tags: java, recursão

Estou tentando criar um método de forma recursiva, que me mostre todos os centros de custo filhos que não tenham outros filhos, por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se o pai for o centro de custo 1, irá me retornar o 3, 4 e 5. O 2 não é retornado porque ele também tem filhos.

O que tentei até agora:

```
public class Teste {

    public static List<CentroCusto> centroCustos = new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<CentroCusto> centroCustos2 = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        build();

        CentroCusto c1 = new CentroCusto();
        c1.setId(1L);
        buscarFilhos(c1);
        System.out.println(centroCustos2);
    }

    private static CentroCusto buscarFilhos(CentroCusto ccu) {
        if (!centroCustos.stream().map(CentroCusto::getCentroCustoPai).filter(Objects::nonNull).anyMatch(centroCusto -> centroCusto.getId().equals(ccu.getId()))) {
            centroCustos2.add(ccu);
            return ccu;
        }
        for (CentroCusto centroCusto : centroCustos) {
            if (Objects.nonNull(centroCusto.getCentroCustoPai()) && centroCusto.getCentroCustoPai().getId().equals(ccu.getId())) {
                return buscarFilhos(centroCusto);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static void build() {
        CentroCusto c1 = new CentroCusto();
        c1.setId(1L);
        CentroCusto c2 = new CentroCusto();
        c2.setId(2L);
        c2.setCentroCustoPai(c1);
        CentroCusto c3 = new CentroCusto();
        c3.setId(3L);
        c3.setCentroCustoPai(c2);
        CentroCusto c4 = new CentroCusto();
        c4.setId(4L);
        c4.setCentroCustoPai(c2);
        CentroCusto c5 = new CentroCusto();
        c5.setId(5L);
        c5.setCentroCustoPai(c1);
        CentroCusto c6 = new CentroCusto();
        c6.setId(6L);
        CentroCusto c7 = new CentroCusto();
        c7.setId(7L);
        c7.setCentroCustoPai(c6);
        CentroCusto c8 = new CentroCusto();
        c8.setId(8L);
        c8.setCentroCustoPai(c7);
        centroCustos.add(c1);
        centroCustos.add(c2);
        centroCustos.add(c3);
        centroCustos.add(c4);
        centroCustos.add(c5);
        centroCustos.add(c6);
        centroCustos.add(c7);
        centroCustos.add(c8);
    }

}

public class CentroCusto {
    private Long id;
    private CentroCusto centroCustoPai;
    // Gettes e Setters
}
```

Comment: "_Se o pai for o centro de custo 1, ira me retornar o 3, 4 e 5_"  O centro de custo 2 também é filho do 1, por que não deve aparecer?

Comment: Porque o centro de custo 2 é pai do 3 e 4. Queria listar apenas os que não possuem filhos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que fica mais fácil se cada `CentroCusto` tiver uma lista dos filhos:

```
public class CentroCusto {
    private Long id;
    private CentroCusto pai;
    private List<CentroCusto> filhos; // lista dos filhos

    public CentroCusto(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        // todos começam órfãos e sem filhos
        this.filhos = new ArrayList<>();
        this.pai = null;
    }

    public void addFilho(CentroCusto filho) {
        this.filhos.add(filho); // adiciona na lista de filhos
        filho.pai = this; // atualiza o pai do filho recém-adicionado
    }

    public boolean temFilhos() {
        return this.filhos.size() > 0;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public CentroCusto getPai() {
        return pai;
    }

    public void mostrarDescendentesSemFilhos() {
        for (CentroCusto c : this.filhos) {
            if (c.temFilhos()) {
                c.mostrarDescendentesSemFilhos();
            } else {
                System.out.println(c.getId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Também criei um construtor que recebe o `id`, e criei um método que adiciona um filho (e repare que este método já atualiza o `pai` do `CentroCusto` adicionado como filho).

E removi os *setters*, pois não me parecem necessários (alguém pode mudar de `pai` ou de `id` deliberadamente?). Enfim, detalhes...

---

Assim fica mais fácil fazer a recursão (mudei o nome do método para `mostrarDescendentesSemFilhos`, pois no fundo é isso que ele faz, já que ele pode mostrar um neto, bisneto, etc, e não somente um filho direto). A ideia é percorrer a lista de filhos, e para cada um:

- se não tiver filhos, mostra
- se tiver, chama o método recursivamente, assim ela irá percorrer os filhos do filho (e verá se eles têm descendentes, chamando o método novamente caso necessário, e assim por diante)

O método agora é `void` porque ele não retorna nada, só imprime. Não fazia sentido ele retornar um único `CentroCusto`, já que na verdade pode ter mais de um. Então no `main` ficaria assim:

```
CentroCusto c1 = new CentroCusto(1L);
CentroCusto c2 = new CentroCusto(2L);
c2.addFilho(new CentroCusto(3L));
c2.addFilho(new CentroCusto(4L));
c1.addFilho(c2);
c1.addFilho(new CentroCusto(5L));
CentroCusto c6 = new CentroCusto(6L);
CentroCusto c7 = new CentroCusto(7L);
c7.addFilho(new CentroCusto(8L));
c6.addFilho(c7);

System.out.println("Descendentes de c1:");
c1.mostrarDescendentesSemFilhos();  // imprime 3, 4 e 5
System.out.println("Descendentes de c6:");
c6.mostrarDescendentesSemFilhos(); // imprime 8
```

---

Se em vez de imprimir, você quiser retornar os próprios objetos, então o método deveria retornar uma lista:

```
public class CentroCusto {
    ... o resto do código é igual

    public List<CentroCusto> getDescendentesSemFilhos() {
        List<CentroCusto> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CentroCusto c : this.filhos) {
            if (c.temFilhos()) {
                // tem filhos, procura pelos descendentes recursivamente e adiciona na lista
                list.addAll(c.getDescendentesSemFilhos());
            } else {
                list.add(c); // não tem filhos, adiciona na lista
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Só que agora no `main` você precisará percorrer a lista, caso queira saber quais são:

```
System.out.println("Descendentes de c1:");
// imprime 3, 4 e 5
for (CentroCusto c : c1.getDescendentesSemFilhos()) {
    System.out.println(c.getId());
}
System.out.println("Descendentes de c6:");
// imprime 8
for (CentroCusto c : c6.getDescendentesSemFilhos()) {
    System.out.println(c.getId());
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela solução, ficou muito top! Infelizmente eu precisava de uma solução sem alterar a classe CentroCusto, eu alterei a minha classe, acho que eu consegui, vou postar aqui, obrigado! :D

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que consegui, vou postar o fonte:

```
public class Teste {

    public static List<CentroCusto> centroCustos = new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<CentroCusto> centroCustos2 = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        build();
        CentroCusto c1 = centroCustos.get(0);
        imprimirRecursivamente(c1);

        for (CentroCusto centroCusto : centroCustos2) {
            if (isFilho(centroCusto)) {
                System.out.println(centroCusto.getId() + " é filho.");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void imprimirRecursivamente(CentroCusto cc) {
        for (CentroCusto filho : getFilhos(cc)) {
            imprimirRecursivamente(filho);
            centroCustos2.add(filho);
        }
    }

    private static List<CentroCusto> getFilhos(CentroCusto cc) {
        List<CentroCusto> ccus = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CentroCusto centroCusto : centroCustos) {
            if (Objects.nonNull(centroCusto.getCentroCustoPai()) &&
                    centroCusto.getCentroCustoPai().getId().equals(cc.getId())) {
                ccus.add(centroCusto);
            }
        }
        return ccus;
    }

    private static boolean isFilho(CentroCusto ccu) {
        return !centroCustos.stream().map(CentroCusto::getCentroCustoPai).filter(Objects::nonNull).anyMatch(centroCusto -> centroCusto.getId().equals(ccu.getId()));
    }

    private static void build() {
        CentroCusto c1 = new CentroCusto();
        c1.setId(1L);
        CentroCusto c2 = new CentroCusto();
        c2.setId(2L);
        c2.setCentroCustoPai(c1);
        CentroCusto c3 = new CentroCusto();
        c3.setId(3L);
        c3.setCentroCustoPai(c2);
        CentroCusto c4 = new CentroCusto();
        c4.setId(4L);
        c4.setCentroCustoPai(c2);
        CentroCusto c5 = new CentroCusto();
        c5.setId(5L);
        c5.setCentroCustoPai(c1);
        CentroCusto c6 = new CentroCusto();
        c6.setId(6L);
        CentroCusto c7 = new CentroCusto();
        c7.setId(7L);
        c7.setCentroCustoPai(c6);
        CentroCusto c8 = new CentroCusto();
        c8.setId(8L);
        c8.setCentroCustoPai(c7);
        centroCustos.add(c1);
        centroCustos.add(c2);
        centroCustos.add(c3);
        centroCustos.add(c4);
        centroCustos.add(c5);
        centroCustos.add(c6);
        centroCustos.add(c7);
        centroCustos.add(c8);
    }

}
```